# Merge Features with topojson via make?

Tags: json, makefile, geojson, topojson

I'd like to create GeoJSON/topojson files of all the continents. That is, I'd like Europe to be one Feature, for example.

I have all of the countries in the world, broken down by continent (using Natural Earth data). I can create separate JSON files for each continent.

I've seen where topojson.js can do it on the client side (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/5416405/), but I'd prefer to do it before serving to the client.

**How do I merge the features (countries) into one shape via shell ?**

Comment: Are you prepared to use Postgis? Or do you want to stick to the Javascript world. There are a couple of options, depending on your answer.

Comment: thank you. I ended up doing it in QGIS, and it worked well.

Comment: That would work. I was going to suggest using https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts, if you wanted to work entirely in Javascript and be able to do this kind of thing on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

@mbostock does something like

```
build/%.json: build/%-unmerged.json
    node_modules/.bin/topojson-merge \
        -o $@ \
        --in-object=$* \
        --out-object=$* \
        -- $<
```

in the blocks [Swiss Cantons & Lake](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/10024231) But I wasn't able to clearly understand this block of code.